# Schema Comparison causes Visual Studio 2010 to crash

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008-r2

When I click on **Write Updates** and then I confirm, VS stops working. What could be the issue here?

I'm trying to update the database project schema directly from the source database using a schema comparison, as it seems it is the absolute best way to sync those, but I seem unable to execute it on the target project. I haven't tried targeting a database.

[image]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSUpQ.png